# jQuery: Select both inner and outer first elements with classname within parent

Tags: jquery, html-table, selector

I need jQuery to select **both** first and last elements with the `.is` classname in a table row, not just the outer first and last elements. Regular `.next()` and `prev()` sibling selectors don't seem to work here. Multiple rows are generated dynamically. Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

**This is my jQuery right now:**

```
$('.row-months').each((i, el) => {
    $(el).find('.is:first').toggleClass('is isf'); // Indoor sow
    $(el).find('.is:last').toggleClass('is isl');
});
```

**This is how it selects the table cells:**

```
<tr class="row-months">
  <td class="cell-month cell-jan jan1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-jan jan2"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-feb feb1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-feb feb2 is"></td> <!-- Select: First ".is" -->
  <td class="cell-month cell-mar mar1 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-mar mar2 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-apr apr1 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-apr apr2 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-may may1 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-may may2"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-jun jun1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-jun jun2"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-jul jul1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-jul jul2 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-aug aug1 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-aug aug2 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-sep sep1 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-sep sep2 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-oct oct1 is"></td> <!-- Select: Last ".is" -->
  <td class="cell-month cell-oct oct2"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-nov nov1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-nov nov2"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-dec dec1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-dec dec2"></td>
</tr>
```

**This is how I need jQuery to select the cells:**

```
<tr class="row-months">
  <td class="cell-month cell-jan jan1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-jan jan2"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-feb feb1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-feb feb2 is"></td> <!-- Select: Outer first ".is" -->
  <td class="cell-month cell-mar mar1 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-mar mar2 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-apr apr1 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-apr apr2 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-may may1 is"></td> <!-- Select: Inner last ".is" -->
  <td class="cell-month cell-may may2"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-jun jun1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-jun jun2"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-jul jul1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-jul jul2 is"></td> <!-- Select: Inner first ".is" -->
  <td class="cell-month cell-aug aug1 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-aug aug2 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-sep sep1 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-sep sep2 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-oct oct1 is"></td> <!-- Sekect: Outer last "is" -->
  <td class="cell-month cell-oct oct2"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-nov nov1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-nov nov2"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-dec dec1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-dec dec2"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Did you have a go at just looping through the `td`s and comparing with the previous?  Might not be a "fancy" solution, but would work with minimal effort.

Comment: I thought I was already looping through the elements this way. What does such loop look like?

Comment: same as you already have: `$('.row-months').each((i, tr) => { $(tr).find("td.is").each((i, td) => {`

Comment: I might be doing something wrong. Isn't this supposed to loop through the TDs within the TRs? `$('.row-months').each((i, tr) => { $(tr).find("td.is").each((i, td) => { $(el).find('.is:first').toggleClass('is isf'); $(el).find('.is:last').toggleClass('is isl'); }); });`

Comment: What's `$(el)`?  Should be `$(td)` - or whatever you put in the `.each((i, td) =>`  - the inner loop is already looping `td`s so no need to `.find` them.   More like `if (!$(td).prev().hasClasS("is")) $(td).addClass("isf")...`

Comment: Ahhhh I got it. Many thanks, the issue is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of [jQuery Next Adjacent Selector (“prev + next”)](https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/)

> Description: Selects all next elements matching "next" that are
> immediately preceded by a sibling "prev".

Do note, this won't work if the `td.is` is the very first child or very last child of `tr.row-months`, in that case `:first` and `:last` selector could be used.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     
     $('.row-months').find(':not(.is) + .is').toggleClass('is isf');
     $('.row-months').find('.is + :not(.is)').prev().toggleClass('is isl');

});
```

```css
td { padding: 10px; background-color: grey; }
td.isf { background-color: green; }
td.isl { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="row-months">
  <td class="cell-month cell-jan jan1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-jan jan2"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-feb feb1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-feb feb2 is"></td> <!-- Select: First ".is" -->
  <td class="cell-month cell-mar mar1 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-mar mar2 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-apr apr1 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-apr apr2 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-may may1 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-may may2"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-jun jun1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-jun jun2"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-jul jul1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-jul jul2 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-aug aug1 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-aug aug2 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-sep sep1 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-sep sep2 is"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-oct oct1 is"></td> <!-- Select: Last ".is" -->
  <td class="cell-month cell-oct oct2"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-nov nov1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-nov nov2"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-dec dec1"></td>
  <td class="cell-month cell-dec dec2"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```